# For Monarch, how do you consider which are Garments and Beasts?

Tags: monarch

For Monarch, there's no way to know if a court card is a beast/garment. Such as for example: The court card Wardrobe Master states that *"get 3 crown values per each GARMENT court cards"*. Is it just going to be a consensus among sisters if they consider a card as a garment card? Such as the *Ceremonial Comb* court card? Or how about for beasts? Is a *pomeranian* court card a beast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've consulted [the official manual](http://playmonarch.com/wp-content/uploads/20160104-monarch-instructions-revised-screenres.pdf).There, it says you can identify certain card sub-types by their emblems. All Beasts have a white beast-emblem printed behind the text, all Garments have a cloak, etc. Here's an excerpt from the rulebook, page 4:

[image: Monarch rulebook, p.4]

See the white emblem laced in the text on the lower part of the card?

Also, this exact question is featured in [their FAQ](http://playmonarch.com/faqs/).

Comment: Hi, I'm assuming you meant the ones such as `Bounty`, `Wisdom`, and `Culture`? Those are Court Card Types, there are 4 of them to be exact, the other one being `Might`. They don't say which ones are `Garments` or `Beasts` though, such as `Dragon Phoenix Gown`, I'm assuming is a garment due to it being a "gown".

Comment: @Takeshi I've found the manual and edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Omg @steenbergh, That's perfect! I didn't quite took notice of those emblems! Wow! Great find!